# Cash-Or-Nothing Option pricing formula when volatility and interest rate go zero

Tags: black-scholes, cash-or-nothing

How does Cash-Or-Nothing Call Option (Fix payoff if S > K) pricing formula behaves when volatility and interest rate both go zero? Say for the scenario of deep out of money (eg. S = 0.5 x K), or the scenario of deep in the money (eg. S = 2 x K)?

My understanding is that when volatility goes zero, the underlying price does not move, and whether it will be in the money (S > K at expiry) or out of money should depends on S at beginning. However from the pricing formula it seems that d2 becomes infinity when volatility goes zero, regardless of where S is, which confuses me.

Comment: Hi Henry! $d_2=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{F}{K}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}$. As $\sigma\to0$, the sign of $\ln\left(\frac{F}{K}\right)$ determines the limit (ie, the option's moneyness).